# Yii renderpartial Eselect2 Design it's not Working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I want to Show My data in Popup,Once User Selected Department Showing that

Staff's names related to user Selected Department using Ajax,Geeting

data's Correctly But Am showing that Staff's names in Eselect2 Widget

Multiple option in Yii,that Eselect2  Design Not coming Its showing normal

Select  Dropdown user Choose multiple choice using ctrl Keys .

My Codings, in that Div staff I am showing that eselect2 widget data's.

Ajax Coding

```
<div id ="staffs></div>

function selectstaff(id)
{

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("user/users/ajaxselectstaff"); ?>',
        data: 'id=' + id,
        success: function (packages) {
            $('#staffs').html(packages);
        }
    });

}
```

Controller Coding

```
public function actionAjaxselectstaff() {
    $id = Yii::app()->request->getPost('id');       
    $model = Users::model()->getAllStaffDepartment($id);
    $this->renderPartial('ajaxselect', array('model' => $model));
}
```

MOdel Coding,

```
public function getAllStaffDepartment($id, $type = '') {
    $model = UserAccount::model()->findAll('department_code=:id', array(':id' => $id));
    $userid = "";
    $result = "";
    if (isset($model)) {
        foreach ($model as $data) {
            $userid .= $data->user_id . ",";
        }
    }
    $userid = trim($userid, ',');
    if ($userid != "") {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = "user_role_id!=" . Yii::app()->mconstant->CONST_FIVE . " AND user_role_id!= " . Yii::app()->mconstant->CONST_SIX . " AND user_role_id!= " . Yii::app()->mconstant->CONST_NINE . " AND user_id IN (" . $userid . ")";
        $result = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $data = CHtml::listData($result, 'user_id', 'real_name');
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ajaxselect page:

```
<?php

Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = false;
if ($model) {
?>
<?php

$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
    'name' => 'users',
    'id' => 'users',
    'data' => $model,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'multiple' => true,
        'placeholder' => 'Select Users',
    ),
));
?>
<?php

  } else {
  echo "No Staff's Found";
 }
?>
```

what's wrong in my code ? Am changes the page to render eselect2 widget design getting properly but render partial eselect2 design not getting,

Answer (score 1):

There is small change in controller which is mention below.

```
public function actionAjaxselectstaff() {
    $id = Yii::app()->request->getPost('id');       
    $model = Users::model()->getAllStaffDepartment($id);
    $this->renderPartial('ajaxselect', array('model' => $model) ,false , true);
}
```

Please find description of third and forth paramerter of renderPartial in below link : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail